# Can't Connect C# with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, parallels

I am trying to write a program which interacts with my SQL Server database. I am programming in C# on Parallels on my Mac and SQL Server is running via Docker.

But I just can't connect. I am just getting the same error every time I try.

I have already tried to allow the remote access on SQL Server with:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

but this does not solve my problem.

Here is my C# code:

main Class

```
Database database;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    database = new Database("localhost\\MSSQLSERVER", "user1", "topsecret", "master"); // \
}

private void connect_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database.Connect();
}
```

Database class:

```
class Database
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder;
    SqlConnection connection;

    public Database(string source, string userid, string password, string initialcatalog){
        this.builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        this.builder.DataSource = source;
        this.builder.UserID = userid;
        this.builder.Password = password;
        this.builder.InitialCatalog = initialcatalog;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        try 
        {
            // Connect to SQL
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
            this.connection = new SqlConnection(this.builder.ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
        catch(SqlException sqle)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sqle.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And I am always getting this error:

> Network-related or instance-specific error when connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - connection string invalid)

Comment: You have to follow different steps to get access.
do you have an account on the sql server?
like username and password?

Comment: Yes I have created one like this before: 

create login user1 with password = 'topsecret',
       default_database = master,
       check_expiration = off,
       check_policy = off;
go

and i can login with this user

Comment: But i also have tried it with my sa account before and i am still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have Database on same PC or different?

Comment: Database is running on the same PC

Comment: The error is not a logon error, it's a communication error.

Comment: I suggest you download Azure Data Studio (runs on Mac) and see if you can connect. Can you use docker command line tools to confirm the SQL Server is running? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash

Comment: My Database is running perfectly on Azure Data Studio...

Comment: Ok the error says connection string invalid and we know you can connect so the issue is in your C# code. Just don’t know where.

Comment: Don't you think that there could be some issue with the docker sql configuration or something with the firewall? But i just cant find anything...

Comment: You just tested and discovered that you can connect fine with one client app (Azure Data Studio), but you can't connect with your C# code. So it appears your SQL Server is fine but your code isn't. I suggest you put a breakpoint and debug and check the connection string - that's what the error says.

Comment: What host name did you connect to in Azure Data Studio? It would not have been `localhost\MSSQLSERVER`, it would've been `localhost` right?

Comment: Yes just to 'localhost'

Comment: I have tried the same Code now on my old PC where I run Sql Studio and Visual Studio in one Partition without docker everything on Windows and it works fine....

Comment: OK so to clarify your code now has `localhost`, not `localhost\\MSSQLSERVER` right?

Comment: Yes but because i was using Visual Studio in Parallels and Parallels cant use localhost so i had to set the ip of the localhost from paralles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Problem with Parallels, because Paralles can not access to localhost. So i had to define the IP from Parallels in Visual Studio like this:

```
database = new Database("10.211.55.2", "user1", "topsecret", "Time");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MSSQLSERVER` is the instance name of the **unnamed, default** instance on your machine - you **must not** use this in the connection string.

Instead, try this line of code:

```
database = new Database("localhost", "user1", "topsecret", "master");
```

Just specify **no explicit instance name** at all - just `localhost` (or `(local)`, or `.`) for the current machine - that's all you need!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick answer, but it is still not working...
Nevermind if I use 'localhost, '(local)' or '.'